# how we can get which validation is invalid in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have this code to figure out if the element is valid or invalid in my directive :

```
myModule.directive('myDirective',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl){

        if(ctrl.$invalid){
            //do something
        }
    }
}});
```

So my problem is how can I determine which type of validation is invalid, required? max-length? my other custom-validations?

Because I need to generate proper validation-message to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) (or `ctrl`, in your example) has an `$error` property that you can use to see what the validation errors are.

So if the "required" validation has failed, this property will be truthy: `ctrl.$error.required`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might need to look into `$error` of your `ctrl` object.

Take a look at the following:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Look for references of `$error`. There are some specific examples there that might be of help to you.

For example:

```
<div ng-show="form.uEmail.$dirty && form.uEmail.$invalid">Invalid:
  <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
  <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
</div>
```